# Prevent sharing of class variables with base class in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance, class-variables

I have the following situation in Python 3:

```
class A:
    d = {}

class B(A):  pass
class C(A):  pass
```

I work with the classes only, no instances get created.  When I access `B.d` I will get a shared reference to `A.d`.  That's not what I want.  I would like to have each class which inherits `A` have its own `d` which is set to a dictionary.  `d` is an implementation detail to `A`.  All access to `d` is done in the code of `A`.  Just `B`'s `d` should not be identical to `A`'s `d`.

With instances, I would create that dictionary in the `__init__()` function.  But in my case I work with the classes only.

Is there a standard way to achieve this (EDIT: without changing the implementation of the subclasses `B` and `C`)?  Is there something analog to `__init__()` which gets called for (or in) each derived class at the time of deriving?

Comment: Well, you should be able to define d in the other classes which would overwrite the d variable from the base class for B and C. Or is that not working?

Comment: Looks like a design issue. Why are you *not* using instances of your classes, and all your problems go away?

Comment: @timgeb Because the "and all problems go away" is not correct.  It raises other problems I did not address in my question.  Using classes is the "right way" in some cases; let's just assume I have such a case.

Comment: @meissner_ The existence of `d` in `A` is an implementation detail of `A`.  When deriving `A` I want to avoid having to mention `d` at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution myself using a metaclass:

```
class M(type):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.d = {}

class A(metaclass=M): pass
```

Then one can create subclasses of `A` which all have their own `d` attribute:

```
class B(A): pass

B.d is A.d
False
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply testing @meissner_ comment: you can easily replace the `d` inside your subcalsses by other ones.

```
class BaseA():
    """Provides basic initialization for dicts used in A() and deriveds."""
    @classmethod
    def InitDefaults(cls):
        return { 1: "this", 2:"are", 3:"some", 4:"defaults"}

class A():
    d = BaseA.InitDefaults()

class B(A):
    d = BaseA.InitDefaults()

class C(A):
    d = BaseA.InitDefaults()


print(A.d)
print(B.d)
print(C.d)

print("\n")
B.d[99] = "Not a default"
C.d[42] = "Not THE answer"

print(A.d)
print(B.d)
print(C.d)
```

Output:

```
{1: 'this', 2: 'are', 3: 'some', 4: 'defaults'}
{1: 'this', 2: 'are', 3: 'some', 4: 'defaults'}
{1: 'this', 2: 'are', 3: 'some', 4: 'defaults'}


{1: 'this', 2: 'are', 3: 'some', 4: 'defaults'}
{1: 'this', 2: 'are', 3: 'some', 4: 'defaults', 99: 'Not a default'}
{1: 'this', 2: 'are', 3: 'some', 4: 'defaults', 42: 'Not THE answer'}
```

This is kinda ugly but would work. You have a central place for code modifying the "base-default" and A,B,C get distinct dicts - initted the same - that can develop into different directions.

Probably better would be to use Instances and **init**() though ...

Comment: Of course I want to avoid copying the creation into each derived class.  That this thing `d` even exists is an implementation detail.

Comment: @Alfe If your dicts are partially the same, create a classmethod (in A) that returns a newly build dict with the defaults. Thats one is used by B and C to create it's initial dict once. Code creation placed once, seperate dicts afterwards. If you want diffenrent dicts you need to create them trice for three classes - or copy or w/e. Or use instances.

Comment: Sounds promising! :)  Could you elaborate in your answer?

Comment: As I said, this doesn't solve my issue because it still mentions the implementation detail `d` in the subclasses.  There are lots of inheriting classes which are not under my control (users of my library providing `A`) which are supposed not to change.  So having to mention `d` in each subclass is no option.

Comment: I updated my Q to reflect on this desire not to have to change all subclasses.

Comment: You might be interested in the solution I found using a meta class.